# User Control binding not working for nested property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a user control called InformationControl. I am using it in my window, like this:

```
<general:InformationControl Grid.Row="0" TimeToStart="{Binding TimeToStart}" Poor="{Binding Path=Mine.Poor}" Status="{Binding Path=Mine.MineStatus}"/>
```

The binding on the TimeToStart dependency property is working fine, but when I use `Path=Object.Property` is doesn't seem to work.

However, when I use `Path=Object.Property` on a regular control (i.e. not a UserControl) then it works fine:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Mine.Participants}">
```

I'm breaking in the getter for Mine, and in the binding logging it is saying that it is null, but it has definitely been set. Also the fact that it's trying to get the property in the first place makes me feel like the binding is correct but I can't work out why it's not working.

Do I need to do something different to make sure binding for nested properties works on UserControl dependency properties ?

Comment: What is the DataContext of your InformationControl? And I'm confused. In the ItemsControl where it works you tried Mine.Participants, where is the TimeToStart?

Comment: DataContext for InformationControl isn't set. I didn't think that was necessary for dependency properties ? The point i'm trying to make about the ItemsControl is that Path=Object.Property is working, but it's not working for the user control. Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the order of setting the properties and when Mine.Property is used by your user control?  It is possible that you are trying to set it after your user control is already starting to load.

Comment: DataContext for InformationControl is necessary and that you are expecting that a property called Mine is on that object's datacontext then you can do nested properties.

Comment: @gavin It doesn't matter if it is trying to set it after the user control is already starting to load because he is doing Binding so it will update the values.

Comment: @Leo But i'm setting the DataContext of the window to itself, i.e. this.DataContext = this. So shouldn't the Market property be available to the user control ? Why is it working for the ItemsControl and not InformationControl ?

Comment: @gavin - I started a thread that periodically raises the property changed event for Mine seconds after loading and it is still not working.

Comment: Leo is right, nested properties should work even with user control as long as you have the usercontrol binded to the parent object: Parent object { Mine object { Property you want to bind to}}}. I don't know why you are setting this.DataContext = this, but when I use relative source, I have to do something like this: Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteEventFundCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Where DataContext is the actual property name you have to specify

Comment: @gavin - could you provide an example in an answer and elaborate as I don't fully understand your suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: If you are setting the DataContext to the Window itself, then make sure that the InformationControl inherited the DataContext of the Window, double check that. And from there it should still be the same using the Mine.PropertyName.

Answer (score 1):

Code behind for information control, set a break point at Debug.Print("newvalue...")

```
namespace WpfStackoverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for InformationControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class InformationControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeToStartProperty;
        static InformationControl()
        {
            //FrameworkPropertyMetadata metadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("");
            TimeToStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TimeToStart", typeof(string), typeof(InformationControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, UsernamePropertyChangedCallback));
        }

        public string TimeToStart
        {
            get { 
                return (string)GetValue(TimeToStartProperty); 
            }
            set { 
                SetValue(TimeToStartProperty, value); 
            }
        }

        public InformationControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string temp = TimeToStart;

        }
        private static void UsernamePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Print("OldValue: {0}", e.OldValue);
            Debug.Print("NewValue: {0}", e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Main window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackoverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfStackoverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:InformationControl TimeToStart="{Binding Mine.Name}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Main window code behind:

```
namespace WpfStackoverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Parent p = new Parent();
            p.Mine = new Mine();
            p.Mine.Name = "Hello world";
            this.DataContext = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Parent class:

```
namespace WpfStackoverflow
{


    public class Parent:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Mine _mine;
        public Mine Mine
        {
            get
            {
                return _mine;
            }
            set
            {
                _mine = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
    public class Mine : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

}
```

I really have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, but if you look at my example, getting Mine.Name works in the user control if you set a break point in InformationControl's dependency property change callback. also note that the setter is never called because clr bypass setter and call setvalue directly.